# Automatic labeling of enumeration items

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, enumitem

I would like to redefine the `enumerate` environment so that each `\item` automatically sets `\label{en:\arabic{page}\alph{enumi}}`. I already tried

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\gappto{\item}{\label{en:\arabic{page}\alph{enumi}}}
```

but this also triggers in the `center` environement, where I don't want it.

How can I do this, avoiding conflict with `enumitem.sty` if possible.

(Don't worry about non-uniqueness of labels - the document layout assures that.)

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? What will happen to your `\ref` commands if you have to insert an item before the end of a list?

Comment: @IanThompson Won't happen. I'm re-typesetting an old document, so content is fixed - but style of cross-references in the new edition isn't yet.

Comment: What about page breaks?

Comment: @IanThompson Trust me, in the section where I need this, there will be no dynamic typesetting at all. It's all static, drilled to look like the original - and I'm too lazy to type all the `\label` commands by hand, as one involuntary mishap might mess that up.

Comment: Do you need to worry about nested lists (i.e. enumerates inside other enumerates)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the internal `\@item`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@item}{\label{en:\arabic{page}\alph{enumi}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First.
\item Second.
\item Third.
\end{enumerate}
\ref{en:1c}, \ref{en:1b} and~\ref{en:1a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And an example with the `enumitem` package and nested environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@item}{
  \ifnum\@enumdepth=1\relax
    \label{en:\arabic{page}\alph{enumi}}
  \else 
  \ifnum\@enumdepth=2\relax
    \label{en:\arabic{page}\arabic{enumii}}
  \else 
  \ifnum\@enumdepth=3\relax
    \label{en:\arabic{page}\roman{enumiii}}
  \else 
  \ifnum\@enumdepth=4\relax
    \label{en:\arabic{page}\Roman{enumiv}}
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
  }
  {}{}
\makeatother

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=(\roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label=\Roman*.,label=\Roman*}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First subitem.
  \item Second subitem.
  \item Third subitem.
  \item Fourth subitem.
  \end{enumerate}
\item Second.
\item Third.
\end{enumerate}
Some cross-references for the first level: \ref{en:1c}, \ref{en:1b} and~\ref{en:1a} and some cross-references for the second level: \ref{en:14}, \ref{en:13}, \ref{en:12} and~\ref{en:11}.

\end{document}
```

[image]