# Using apptocmd inside newenvironment

Tags: environments, etoolbox

I try to produce a document containing an exam and the associated correction.
I want automatic hyperlinks from the question to the associated answer and vice-versa.

Using the solution given by Gonzalo Medina to the question [Automatic labeling of enumeration items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174052/automatic-labeling-of-enumeration-items), I am able to label automatically the different item, and using `setlist` I can produce the necessary hyperlinks.

However, I need my questions to be label `qu:1` or `q:2.a` ant the associated answers to be labeled `rep:1` or `rep:2.a`

Gonzalo Medina's solution is to use something like that :

```
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@item}{
  \ifnum\@enumdepth=1\relax
   \label{qu:\arabic{enumi}}
  \else 
  \ifnum\@enumdepth=2\relax
    \label{qu:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}}
 \fi\fi}{}{}
\makeatother
```

It works fine, but `apptocmd` definitely changes the definition of `\@item`. Unfortunately, when writing the solutions to the question, I will need to redefine `\@item` so that the solutions will be label with `rep` and not `qu`.

Something that seems to work but does not really satifies me is the following MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\hyperref[rep:\arabic{enumi}]{\arabic*.}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\hyperref[rep:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}]{\arabic{enumi}.\alph*.},ref=\alph*}


\begin{document}

Questions : 

\begin{enumerate}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@item}{
  \ifnum\@enumdepth=1\relax
    \label{qu:\arabic{enumi}}
  \else 
  \ifnum\@enumdepth=2\relax
    \label{qu:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}}
\fi\fi}{}{}
\makeatother 
\item A question
\begin{enumerate}
\item A subquestion
\item Another subquestion
\end{enumerate}
\item An other question
\end{enumerate}
\newpage
Solutions : 

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\hyperref[qu:\arabic{enumi}]{\arabic*.}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\hyperref[qu:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}]{\arabic{enumi}.\alph*.},ref=\alph*}

\begin{enumerate}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@item}{
  \ifnum\@enumdepth=1\relax
    \label{rep:\arabic{enumi}}
  \else 
  \ifnum\@enumdepth=2\relax
    \label{rep:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}}
\fi\fi}{}{}
\makeatother 

\item An answer
\begin{enumerate}
\item A sub-answer
\item Another sub-answer
\end{enumerate}
\item Another answer
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The main inconvenient is that a the begin of the questions and the beginning of the answers, I need to manually redefine the effect of `\item` (and use `\setlist`).

I'd like to create two different environment, named `subject` and `solutions` (moreover, this seems compatible with the local effect of `apptocmd`).

So I tried the following :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newenvironment{subject}{
  \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\hyperref[rep:\arabic{enumi}]{\arabic*.}}
  \setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\hyperref[rep:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}]{\arabic{enumi}.\alph*.},ref=\alph*}
  \makeatletter
  \apptocmd{\@item}{
    \ifnum\@enumdepth=1\relax
      \label{qu:\arabic{enumi}}
    \else 
    \ifnum\@enumdepth=2\relax
      \label{qu:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}}
  \fi\fi}{}{}
  \makeatother
}{}

\newenvironment{solution}{
  \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\hyperref[qu:\arabic{enumi}]{\arabic*.}}
  \setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\hyperref[qu:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}]{\arabic{enumi}.\alph*.},ref=\alph*}
  \makeatletter
  \apptocmd{\@item}{
    \ifnum\@enumdepth=1\relax
      \label{rep:\arabic{enumi}}
    \else 
    \ifnum\@enumdepth=2\relax
      \label{rep:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}}
  \fi\fi}{}{}
  \makeatother
}{}

\begin{document}

Questions : 
\begin{subject}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A question
\begin{enumerate}
\item A subquestion
\item Another subquestion
\end{enumerate}
\item An other question
\end{enumerate}
\end{subject}

\newpage
Solutions : 

\begin{solution}
\begin{enumerate}    
\item An answer
\begin{enumerate}
\item A sub-answer
\item Another sub-answer
\end{enumerate}
\item Another answer
\end{enumerate}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

However, this is not working at all : the labels are not created at all, and it automatically prints `itemitem` at each use of one of the two newly created environments. Why having `\apptocmd` inside `\newenvironment` is a problem ? (and is that THE problem ?).

Comment: `\makeatletter...\makeatother` outside of the environments ;-)

Comment: @MathieuVienney `\makeatletter` must precede code that *mentions* commands with `@` in their name, not be inside code that uses them. SInce your `\newenvironment` definition mentions `\@item`, `\makeatletter` must be before `\newenvironment`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: By the way, why my  (non) solution was printing `itemitem` at each  call of the environment `subject` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know many cases (in fact none) where `\makeatletter...\makeatother` inside of macro is useful. In this case, it would prevent the correct expansion of the `\@item` etc. macros, and `\apptocmd` is applied to `\item` etc.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{subject}{%
  \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\hyperref[rep:\arabic{enumi}]{\arabic*.}}
  \setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\hyperref[rep:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}]{\arabic{enumi}.\alph*.},ref=\alph*}
  \apptocmd{\@item}{%
    \ifnum\@enumdepth=1\relax
      \label{qu:\arabic{enumi}}
    \else 
    \ifnum\@enumdepth=2\relax
      \label{qu:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}}
  \fi\fi}{}{}
}{}

\newenvironment{solution}{%
  \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\hyperref[qu:\arabic{enumi}]{\arabic*.}}
  \setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\hyperref[qu:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}]{\arabic{enumi}.\alph*.},ref=\alph*}
  \apptocmd{\@item}{%
    \ifnum\@enumdepth=1\relax
      \label{rep:\arabic{enumi}}
    \else 
    \ifnum\@enumdepth=2\relax
      \label{rep:\arabic{enumi}.\alph{enumii}}
  \fi\fi}{}{}
}{}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

Questions : 
\begin{subject}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A question
\begin{enumerate}
\item A subquestion
\item Another subquestion
\end{enumerate}
\item An other question
\end{enumerate}
\end{subject}

\newpage
Solutions : 

\begin{solution}
\begin{enumerate}    
\item An answer
\begin{enumerate}
\item A sub-answer
\item Another sub-answer
\end{enumerate}
\item Another answer
\end{enumerate}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I definitely need to read more about `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` to avoid these mistakes. Anyway, I learned something thanks to you !

Comment: @MathieuVienney: You're welcome ;-)